# How to set programmatically property in xml configuration file?

Tags: java, xml, configuration, logback

I have logback configuration xml file, where log filename pattern is specified as:

`"%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}${customName}.log"`

I use time-based rolling policy for timestamp. How I can specify custom name in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You would use [`LoggerContext#putProperty`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/LoggerContext.html#putProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to add your `customName` property:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
...
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
context.putProperty("customName", "foo");
```